# Next.js passing objects and array in query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to pass object (which also contain an array) as query parameter to my request.

```
const fa = {
  'variants.attributes.Clothing_color': {
    terms: ['Navy Blue', 'Golden Croissant'],
  },
};

const serialize = function (obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join('&');
};

const urlP = serialize(fa);
router.push({
  pathname: router.asPath.split('?')[0] as string,
  query: { facets: urlP },
});
```

In my url the query parameter shown as **?facets=variants.attributes.Clothing_color%3D%255Bobject%2520Object%255D**

In my backend I want to use **Object.entries(facets)** but it creates array of each string instead of array of objects.

1.)What is the right way to pass Objects as query parameter in Next.js?
2.)What is the right way to perform Objects.entries() ?

Thanks in  Advance

Comment: You can start having a look at [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: I try it and in typescript it doesn't let me pass objects into URLSearchParams